# Improve SQL query running on mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

2 tables:

- message : { id / thread_id }
- recipient : { id / thread_id / last_message_seen_id }

I want to retrieve recipient ID that have unread message: "I count how many messages from last message seen"

Here the query (works but I am sure there is something more logic/simple):

```
SELECT r.id, (
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM message m 
   WHERE m.thread_id = r.thread_id AND m.id > r.last_seen_message_id
) AS messages 
FROM recipient r
WHERE (
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM message m 
   WHERE m.thread_id = r.thread_id AND m.id > r.last_seen_message_id
) > 0
```

I think the model is simple enough, if you need more details ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT r.id, Count(m.id) as messages
FROM recipient r
    JOIN messages m on m.thread_id = r.thread_id
        AND m.id > r.last_seen_message_id
GROUP BY r.id
```

Comment: How can I get other field than r.id ?(r.title, r.etc...)

Comment: Add them to the Select and the group by (they have to be in both in order for the count to work)

Comment: Depending on server settings, MySQL may not require that you put the other non-aggregated fields in the `GROUP BY` clause, but it is a good practice... and if you weren't (assumably) grouping on `recipient`'s primary key, neglecting to group on them would return inconsistent results for the non-aggregated fields.